# Find which div in array contains ValueA, and return ValueB from it to a new var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

When a button is clicked, I am grabbing the ***current*** value of a Select control, like so...

```
$('#myBtn').on('click', function (clickEvent) {
    var nameSelected = document.getElementById('mySelectControl').getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerText;
    //...
}
```

This is fine. The value is correct. Say the value of `nameSelected` is 'Bob'.

'Bob' also exists elsewhere in my page, in a table. There is more than 1 table, but only 1 of the tables contain the value 'Bob'.

Each table has been assigned the `square` class.

Here is how I find the names (Bob or otherwise), that are in my tables. I am just doing this in Chrome's Console.

**Create an array of each table:**

```
var tables = $('.square').each(function () {
    $(this).html();
})
```

**Grab the table at Index 0 and get the name from the table:**

```
var name = $(tables[0]).find('tr:eq(0)').find('td').text();
```

This all works. The result of the statement above will be 'Bob', or 'Jon', or 'Bill', etc.

What I need is the value of a different `td`, from whichever table contains `nameSelected` (from the Select control above). For example pseudo-code:

```
var phone = $(tables).find('tr:eq(6)').find('td').text();
WHERE
name == nameSelected
```

I hope that makes sense. Basically trying to get the value of `td(6).text` from whichever `div` has `nameSelected` in `td(0).text`.

I am just not sure how to write the last statement and I have tried a few things. I want to do all of this when the button is clicked. I hope the pseudo-code helps...

Comment: Serious. Very serious. `var tables = $$('.square')[0].forEach(function (e) {
    e.innerHTML = this.innerHTML
})` is pure ecma6 javascript. (With higher performance https://www.measurethat.net/benchmarks/Show/11/0/foreach-vs-jquery-each

Comment: https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/02/stop-writing-slow-javascript/

Comment: About «everyone else» think a minute, those who tell that, had paid their school 100k$, 10 years ago and want to protect their cake. Big company that still use jquery are ... dying. No one use it for new projects. (Disclaimer: i had use it a lot, 10 years ago. Then had switch to zepto. ecma6 lives because jquery had exist. All is in it, with ease)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create what you called an *"array of each tables"*. You can place your code right inside the `each()` function and then simply check the name to see if you found who you're looking for (e.g. Bob) and then break so you don't continue searching in the other tables needlessly:

```
var search = 'Bob';
var phone;
$('.square').each(function() {
  var name = $(this).find('tr:eq(0)').find('td').text();
  if (name === search) {
    phone = $(this).find('tr:eq(6)').find('td').text();
    return false; //Break out of the loop.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will have a close look at this in the morning. Thanks again for your efforts! Am I wrong about putting each div in an array? I see that I don’t need to, but thats what I was doing, yeah?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It will work, but you'll be making it work more than necessary, so your code will not be efficient.

Comment: For sure, it would be less efficient. I don’t want to do it. Never mind that part ;).

Comment: So much simpler than I was making it. I must have been fried by the end of the day ;). Thank you for that. Also a note, apparently jQuery .each does not use a loop, so `break` does not work. At least it didn't for me. Thank you again!

Comment: Good catch! Yes, to break out of jQuery `each`, you need to use `return false` instead of `break`. Updated my answer.